Unable to draw rounded stroke in NSAttributedString
I'm trying to apply a rounded stroke effect to text using NSMutableAttributedString in Swift. I have been able to find various NSMutableAttributedString.Key options for text attributes like color, font, and underline, but I can't seem to find any key that allows me to apply a rounded stroke to the text.
let attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .font: font,
    .strokeWidth: borderWidthToDraw,
    .strokeColor: strokeColorToDraw,
]

For better visual support, expected & curent output has been .

I think changing the font to SF rounded might work. Do you mind changing the font?

What's the value of borderWidthToDraw? Positive or negative?

@Larme borderWidthToDraw is a positive number.

@Sweeper I have used for multiple fonts, but not working.

I doubt you can get your desired appearance using an attributed string.
If you're open to another approach, here is an example using a UILabel subclass and overriding drawText(...):
@IBDesignable
class StrokeLabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var strokeSize: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = .clear { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        // we need leading/trailing "padding" for the stroke
        var sz = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return .init(width: sz.width + strokeSize * 2.0, height: sz.height)
    }
    
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        // we need leading/trailing "padding" for the stroke
        let r = rect.insetBy(dx: self.strokeSize, dy: 0.0)

        // save textColor
        let textColor = self.textColor

        // set stroke properties
        context.setLineWidth(self.strokeSize)
        context.setLineJoin(.round)

        // stroke the text
        self.textColor = self.strokeColor
        context.setTextDrawingMode(.stroke)
        super.drawText(in: r)

        // "normal" draw the text
        self.textColor = textColor
        context.setTextDrawingMode(.fill)
        super.drawText(in: r)
    }
}

Example controller:
class TestStrokeLabelVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.975, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let testLabel = StrokeLabel()
        testLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32.0, weight: .bold)
        testLabel.textColor = .black
        testLabel.text = "TIC-TAC-TOE"
        
        testLabel.strokeSize = 5.0
        testLabel.strokeColor = .red
        
        testLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
    
}

Output:

Note: This StrokeLabel class is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69368542/6257435 with a few modifications.

The stroke border will be rounded if the font has rounded ends, such as SF Rounded.
Here I displayed an NSAttributedString in a UITextView, using the SF Rounded font.
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "TIC-TAC-TOE", attributes: [
            .font:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50, weight: .bold).rounded(),
            .strokeWidth: 5,
            .strokeColor: UIColor.red,
        ])
        
        textView.attributedText = attrString
    }
}

// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305343/5133585
extension UIFont {
    func rounded() -> UIFont {
        guard let descriptor = fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded) else {
            return self
        }

        return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: pointSize)
    }
}

Output:

This doesn't look exactly the same as the picture in the question. If you want a rounded stroke but the text itself should be unrounded, I doubt you can do that with NSAttributedString alone. In the worst case, you might have to use CoreText functions like CTFontCreatePathForGlyph to get the paths of the glyphs, and change lineJoin to round.
